# Open cursor in anonymous SQL block in db2 V9.5

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to write a statement to drop all overloaded procs with a name. But can't declare cursor:

```
--<ScriptOptions statementTerminator="^"/>
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE cursor_procs CURSOR FOR select SPECIFICNAME from syscat.procedures where PROCSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' AND PROCNAME = 'CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ARCH' ;
END
^
--<ScriptOptions statementTerminator=";"/>
```

The error is:

```
An unexpected token "FOR" was found following "cursor_procs CURSOR".  Expected tokens may include:  "<SQL_variable_declarations>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
```

Comment: Have you tried without an atomic block

Comment: I can't find any syntax for anonymous blocks other than `BEGIN ATOMIC`

Comment: Just begin? without atomic

Comment: It doesn't work. `An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "BEGIN`

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://www.sqlpl-guide.com/Compound_statements There could be a restriction with cursor in inline SQL PL.